# Fake local filepath on form to image on the web

Tags: filesystems, images, path, imacros

I'm using iMacros to automate posting ads for my property management company. As of right now all image files that we want to upload to various sites (craigslist, zillow, etc) must be stored locally - I'd like to keep our images on a webserver and upload them from there.

The issue is that the image upload forms do not like remote paths. I know you can do this manually in Windows by entering the URI when the 'browse for file' menu pops up. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it where it looks like a local filepath so the process can be automated.

Comment: What browser are you using? Ive seen the "Fake Local Filepath" happen with chrome here recently.

Comment: Firefox -- iMacros for Chrome is very weak currently